# Sketch: combined shape different colors in each shape

Tags: shapes, sketch-app

I am having a little problem. Trying to make a progress bar in Sketch. The combined shape functionality works great for this - but it seems like i can't apply different colors onto the different shapes inside the combined shape?

Check out this image:

[image: Sketch combined shape color]

If i apply the brown color to this circle only, it applies to all the other shapes inside the combined shape. It acts like a global color. Can i disable this somehow?

My goal is to get the first 3 dots and 2 lines to have the brown color, and the rest gray.

Answer (score 1):

Combined shapes are treated as one shape, so any fill or effects you apply are applied to the whole shape, not single subpaths.

What you actually want are separate shapes. I would suggest duplicating the combined shape, layering a brown version over a gray version and either masking or deleting the parts of the brown shape you don't want.